# Scraping JSON object with beautiful soup

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

**Background**

I am attempting to scrape this [page](https://shop.guess.com/en/catalog/browse/men/tanks-t-shirts/view-all/). Basically get the name of each product, it's price and image. I was expecting to see the div's that contain the product in the soup but i did not. So what i did is i opened up the url in my chrome browser and upon doing inspect element in my networks tab i found the GET call it's making is directly to this [page](https://shop.guess.com/en/catalog/browse/men/tanks-t-shirts/view-all/?filter=true&page=1) to get all the product related information. If you open that url you will see basically a JSON object and there is html string in there with the divs for the product and prices. The question for me is how would I parse this?

**Attempted Solution**
I thought one obvious way is to convert the soup in to a JSON and so in order to do that soup needs to be a string and that's exactly what i did. The issue now is that my `json_data` variable basically has a string. So when i attempt to do something like this `json_data['Results']` it gives me and error saying i can only pass ints. I am unsure how to proceed further.

I would love suggestions and any pointers if i am doing something wrong.

Following is My code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
from random_user_agent.params import SoftwareName, OperatingSystem
import requests
import json
import sys


sys.stdout = open('output.html', 'wt')
page_to_scrape = 'https://shop.guess.com/en/catalog/browse/men/tanks-t-shirts/view-all/?filter=true&page=1'
software_names = [SoftwareName.CHROME.value]
operating_systems = [OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.value, OperatingSystem.LINUX.value]
user_agent_rotator = UserAgent(software_names=software_names, operating_systems=operating_systems, limit=100)
page = requests.get(page_to_scrape, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent_rotator.get_random_user_agent()})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
json_data = json.dumps(str(soup))
print(json_data)
```

Comment: The URL you scrape in your code yields a regular product page and not a JSON for me. Are you sure that your examination is correctly reflected in your question and your code?

Comment: `json_data` prints out empty if I run your code. And `soup` is a regular webpage.

Comment: do you have bs4 installed? @petezurich Also are you able to see any of the product divs in your soup??

Comment: Yes I have bs4 installed. Your code runs fine. I just get an empty `json_data`. And `soup` is a regular page, but not JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error might be that `json_data` is a string and not a dict type as `json.dumps(str(soup))` returns a string.Since `json_data` is string, we cannot do `json_data['Results']` and to access any element of string, we need to pass the index and hence the error.

### EDIT

To get `Results` from the response, the code is shown below:

```
json_data = json.loads(str(soup.text))
print(json_data['Results'])
```

Let me know if this helps!!

Comment: Yes, that is the issue, if i pass index it works but when i pass an index value it will return a character of the string at that index and that does not help me parse

Comment: Can you try the updated solution code and let me know if this helps?